# Should I cut tomatoes once they reach the top of the greenhouse?

Tags: tomatoes, greenhouse

I have tomatoes in a greenhouse. Most of the stem is fortified with a curled rod, so they don't break under the weight of their fruits.

Now they have outgrown their rod and are reaching the top of the greenhouse. I am wondering if I should cut them so they don't touch the roof. For once because there is no way I can further physically support them. But also, maybe they should put their strength in the remaining fruits?

Comment: I believe the common commercial support uses a reel of twine as the support, so that that the top of the plant can be lowered as it nears the roof, with the older part of the plant that is no longer in production collecting on the floor (or is it buried to make more roots from?) - I've only read about these systems, never seen one in person.

Comment: Why not just remove a window, and get more tomatoes? They'll do well outside the greenhouse as well as inside.

Comment: Outside there is rain which might encourage fungus groth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this, and it could indeed strengthen the remaining fruits - another option may be to encourage the plant to grow back downwards.

Comment: Or across the top of the ceiling.  That would help shade a bit this part of the season as well.

Comment: I going for sort of an arched design, along the ceiling and then back down again.